# What could be causing a multithreaded/multiprocessed program to deadlock when there are no cyclic locks?

Tags: python, multithreading, deadlock

I have a piece of python code that uses multiprocessing. It runs for a few hours and then gets stuck, in what I assume is a deadlock. The thing is, I can't see how could I have a deadlock as my process is sequential and there's no resource competition:

- main launches all subprocesses and threads
- a `threading.Thread`reader (spawned from main) runs in a loop, reads data and puts in a synced
  queue (`mp.Queue`) `q_in`
- many `multiprocessing.Processor`s  run in a
  loop, calling `q_in.get()`, when they get some data they start
  processing it, and when each of them is done, they put the processed
  data in `q_out`
- another `threading.Thread` spawned from main runs in
  a loop, calls `q_out.get()` and when receives processed data writes
  it to disk.
- Main `joins` all processes/threads and waits for them to
  finish.

When the reader has no more data to read, it puts a special termination flag in the queue, and for any other process/thread, when they read that flag from an incoming queue they put it in an outgoing one and exit.

As you can see, the locking of queues goes in one direction and is not cyclic, so it doesn't seem like there can be a deadlock. However no error or exception is reported, and I am certain this has to do with the asynchrony of operations. What am I missing? I am communicating solely via the queues, which are synchronous.

Comment: Double checking.  You add enough stop tokens to the queue to stop all of the threads?  What you've described will only stop one worker.  A slightly safer alternative could to make q_in be a joinable queue.  The main thread would first do a join on the reader thread (so it knows there is no more work being created), then a join on q_in, so that it knows that all work has been done.  At this point, it can kill all the worker threads using `pool.terminate()`, and `pool.join()` to confirm they are all dead.

Comment: @FrankYellin -- yes, good question: the workers reenter the termination flag to the same queue after they receive it to make sure their siblings also read it. And I believe your solution wouldn't work, since the deadlock happens long before all the work will have been done.

Comment: Okay.   Thanks for the clarification.  It was also unclear.  Without seeing an outline of your code, it's hard to know what the problem is.  Do you have logs or print statements so you can tell what state stuff is in?  Does it die consistently at a particular point?

Comment: Do any of your processes do blocking reads on stdin (or any other blocking reads, for that matter)?  It's possible to deadlock based on full stream/pipe buffers (e.g. process A waiting for process B to read some data so that process A can write some more, meanwhile process B is waiting for process A to read some data so that process B can write some more)

Comment: A couple of thoughts.  #1) Does your program work with just a small amount of data to process?  #2) Have you verified that the verification token is recognized by the worker threads?  Sometimes objects aren't quite the same when they are passed from one multiprocessor to another.  #3) What is your termination condition for the to-disk writer thread?  It can't quit until all the other threads have quit.

Comment: #4) Do you check for exceptions?  If some of your inputs caused an exception in a worker, and the workers didn't check for this, they would die one by one.  You'd see what looked like deadlock.